# How to trigger events on a row in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to test ag-grid functionality and not able to trigger events.

```js
  it('should open Component on double click', () => {
    component.gridOptions.api.setRowData(ordersStub);

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const node = component.gridOptions.api.getRowNode(ordersStub[0].id);
    const nodeData = node.data;

    const element = (fixture.debugElement.nativeElement as HTMLElement).querySelector(`[row-id="${nodeData.id}"]`);

    const onRowDoubleClickedSpy = spyOn(component, 'onRowDoubleClicked');

    element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('dblclick', { bubbles: true, view: window, cancelable: true }));

    expect(onRowDoubleClickedSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The event you are dispatching looks fine. So I think you need a delay between when the event is dispatched, and when you expect the component function to be called:

```
it('should open Component on double click', (done) => {
  ...

  element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('dblclick', { bubbles: true, view: window, cancelable: true }));
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(onRowDoubleClickedSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    done();
  });
});
```

You could also use async tests:

```
it('should open Component on double click', async(async() => {
  ...

  element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('dblclick', { bubbles: true, view: window, cancelable: true }));
  await fixture.whenStable();
  expect(onRowDoubleClickedSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```